# Isolating $a$ from $L=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{ax_2}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I recently reached got a nice answer from my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567486/integrating-int-x-1x-2-sqrt12at-ax-1x-22-dt) but I quickly that the problem would be unreasonable unless $x_1$ is not a variable and always holds some value, preferably 0, which simplifies the problem significantly leading to the above $L=\frac{1}{a}\int_0^{ax_2}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$. I know that you can take the easy first step to get $La=\int_0^{ax_2}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$ and then take a derivative to get rid of the integral, but I am unsure what variable(s) it would make sense to take the derivative in respect to, would I take the derivative in terms of $ax_2$? And then if that was the case, how would I take the derivative of $La$ in respect to $ax_2$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how specifically would I do that, can you give a more explicit answer. As stated, I am uncertain on how to take such a derivative.

Comment: Is the link broken?

Comment: Use Newton's Leibnitz Formula .

Comment: Sorry, L is a dummy constant.

Comment: Link is now fixed, I think...

Comment: $a$ and $x_2$ are both constants, sorry I need to start stating these things in my questions...

Comment: That's true, I guess what I mean is they are all variables that have a relationship represented in the above equation, like $z=x+y$, and I want to manipulate that relationship to obtain more information.

Comment: Which is getting $a$ in terms of $L$ and $x_2$, or $x_2$ in terms of $a$ and $L$, i.e. to express an [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function).

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up for me, I guess I got a little mixed up with the lingo!

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume to have a function $L$ defined in terms of $a,b>0$ as
$$ L(a,b) = \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{ab}\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt \stackrel{t\mapsto au}{=}\int_{0}^{b}\sqrt{1+a^2 u^2}\,du. \tag{0}$$
Geometric interpretation: $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\sqrt{1+f'(u)^2}\,du$ is the length of the graph of $f(x)$ over the interval $[x_0,x_1]$, hence $L(a,b)$ is measuring the length of the parabolic arc $y=\frac{a}{2}u^2$ over the interval $[0,b]$. Assume that we want to express $a$ in terms of $b$ and $L$. This means to solve the trascendental equation

$$ ab \sqrt{1+a^2 b^2}+\operatorname{arcsinh}(ab) = 2aL $$
with respect to $a$. Equivalently, we may solve
$$ \sqrt{1+d^2}+\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}(d)}{d} = \frac{2L}{b}\tag{A} $$
with respect to $d$, then recall $a=\frac{d}{b}$. The last problem is a root finding problem: the function $g(d)=\sqrt{1+d^2}+\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}(d)}{d}$ behaves like $2+\frac{d^2}{3}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin  and like $d+\frac{1+\log(4d^2)}{2d}$ in a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$. Additionally, it is convex over $\mathbb{R}^+$, and this is a real bless, since it implies that $(A)$ can be efficiently solved through [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). A not-so-bad starting point is given by the solution of 
$$ \sqrt{1+d^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}{3}}} = \frac{2L}{b}\tag{B} $$
which can be found in explicit terms by locating the roots of a fourth degree polynomial. A better starting point is provided by the solution of 
$$ \sqrt{1+d^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{d^2}{2}}} = \frac{2L}{b}.\tag{C} $$

A similar problem arising from the study of planetary motion is the notorious [Kepler's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem) (see also [this introduction](https://www.willbell.com/MATH/mc12.htm) to a very nice book on the topic).

Differentiation can also be used to approximate $a(L,b)$, the [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) defined by $(0)$.
 We simply have:
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = \int_{0}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\sqrt{1+a^2 u^2}\,du = \frac{ab\sqrt{1+a^2 b^2}-\operatorname{arcsinh}(ab)}{2a^2}.$$

Through [Huygens' inequality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.00436) we get the approximation 
$$ a\approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{b^2}\sqrt{L^2-b^2+(L-b)\sqrt{L^2+2b L-2b^2}}.\tag{D}$$

Comment: Ok, wow, most of that went _way_ over my head, but I'll see if it makes and sense to me in a bit!

Comment: I tried it out, it seems that part (B) is a good approximation, as I think you suggested, but does not appear to be a solution with some amount of error.

Comment: @AaronQuitta: the solution of $(B)$ is just the starting point for Newton's method, which converges pretty fast to an arbitrarily accurate approximation of the actual solution.

Comment: Ok, I guess, an arbitrary close solution isn't very useful when I am looking for a solution. This may be to much to ask.

Comment: @AaronQuitta: there is no hope of getting an explicit solution from a trascendental equation, in general. We have come to terms that *knowing a number/function* and *knowing arbitrarily accurate approximations of a number/function* are pretty much the same thing. I suggest you to investigate Kepler's problem, it will be illuminating.

Comment: I guess that true, I took a look at Kepler's problem and its honestly illegible to me as I have yet to take any official calculus classes.

Comment: That one also seems wrong but seems to correlate overall.

Comment: @AaronQuitta: why *wrong*? (I have moved it to the main post). I am performing numerical tests and it is a not so bad approximation, especially if $b$ and $L$ are close.

Comment: I'm testing it and it seems constantly off by a bit, ket me double check I typed it right.

Comment: I believe I have typed it correctly... I'll check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Note that evaluating $I = \int \sqrt{1+t^2}\,\, dt$ has already been asked before [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431143/evaluating-int-sqrt1-t2-dt).

Now, calculating the definite integral from $0$ to $ax_2$ gives us the answer as $$\boxed{L = \frac{1}{2a}[\sinh^{-1}(ax_2)+ax_2\sqrt{1+a^2x_2^2}]}$$

Comment: That is true, but from there it only complicates my problem of isolating $a$.

Comment: A side question: can this problem formulated as an instance of Kepler's problem through suitable substitutions?